# Adicionar propriedades HTML À um input via Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Quando eu crio um campo `input-type-text` via Razor, faço algo parecido com isso:

```
@Html.TextBox("nomeTxt", null, new { @class = "form-control", 
                                     @placeholder = "Exemplo de placeholder",  
                                     @type = "text" })
```

Quando quero adicionar propriedades *HTML* à esse input, eu as coloco como fiz com o `@class, @placeholder, @type`

Por exemplo, se eu quiser colocar um `MaxLength`, bastaria adicionar ao final, como em:

```
@Html.TextBox("nomeTxt", null, new { @class = "form-control", 
                                     @placeholder = "Exemplo de placeholder", 
                                     @type = "text", 
                                     @maxlength="10" })
```

Porém, alguns tipos de propriedades eu não consigo adicionar dessa forma. É o caso da `data-date-format`. O Razor não aceita esses hífens.

Como eu poderia criar, via Razor, um *input* como o exemplo abaixo?

```
<input id="txtData" name="txtData" 
                    placeholder="Ex.: 13/10/2019" 
                    data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" 
                    maxlength="10">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso você deve trocar os hífens por *underscore*.

Note que os arrobas são desnecessários nos atributos (fora o `class`), este operador serve apenas para usar como nome alguma palavra reservada da linguagem (`class`, `int`, `string`, etc.).

```
@Html.TextBox("nomeTxt", null, new { @class = "form-control", 
                                 placeholder = "Exemplo de placeholder", 
                                 type = "text",                                      
                                 maxlength="10" 
                                 data_date_format="dd/mm/yyyy" })
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeito, obrigado!